# What is the safest (least dependencies) to log startup in a Blazor app on Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

When my Blazor app first starts, before the ILogger system is initialized (or fails initialization), I want to be able to log four things:

1. The very first line in `main()` - so I know the app started.
2. About to call builder.Build()
3. If there was a problem instantiating the first iLogger instance
4. The `catch` for `main()` to log the exception.

Once `builder.Build()` has successfully completed and the first `iLogger` is instantiated, I then can use the logging system. But if any of that fails, I need logging to somewhere to tell me what failed.

So what system can I use that has as few dependencies as possible?

Comment: Have you checked ApplicationInsights?

Comment: Using the asp.net core build-in log interface and set the log level to trace may achieve your requirement. Other tool I don't think it will work well. If you don't modify the codes for the program.cs

Comment: @BrandoZhang If creating an ILogger object throws an exception - how do I log that? That's my use case. TIA

Comment: @Harshitha ApplicationInsights can have problems getting started. If that happens, then how do I log that issue? TIA

Comment: Even I am keen to know, so I am following this question. The only way I can think of is good old try catch print exception around the statements you want to track. If even system.io fails, then there is nothing you can do!

Comment: @MayurEkbote Right. But in that catch, if I can not yet create an ILogger, how do I post that exception somewhere?

Comment: Yes. That makes me curious - if you are assuming the server is in such a state that it cannot even perform a simple file I/O then it is highly unlikely that any other mode of communication is available either! So 1. Write your 'bootstrap' log to a simple file. 2. When all other services are up (ILogger etc) read the file and write the contents to ILogger. 2. In case ILogger itself fails, access the file remotely and read what happened.

Comment: @MayurEkbote I recently had a problem where the managed identity was configured wrong. It caused the startup to fail before the build() call and therefore when the exception was thrown, I couldn't log it. That's what I want to handle - errors before build() is called.

Comment: How about try catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

Comment: @DavidThielen Use try catch, log it to the console and check the Azure Streaming Logs (assuming you have deployed on AppService). This has been very handy to check the errors that happen *before* blazor server is up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` or `Trace`. If those don't work the system is not loading.

h/t to a friend who gave me the suggestion.